# Two different versions of Newtonsoft.Json.dll needed in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, dll, json.net, assembly-binding-redirect

I have developed a MVC application that has dependency on Connectwise SDK that uses Newtonsoft.Json.dll v6.0.0.0 and Dropbox SDK that uses Newtonsoft.Json.dll v7.0.0.0.

I need to ensure that my project uses the appropriate dll when needed.
After researching, I tried the following:
- Placed the 2 dlls under sub-folders /dlls/6.0.0.0/ and /dlls/7.0.0.0 resp.
- Referenced version 6.0.0.0 dll in project References
- Added to web.config

```
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
        <dependentAssembly>
          <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed"
            culture="neutral" />
          <bindingredirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0"></bindingredirect>          
        </dependentAssembly>
       <dependentAssembly>
          <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed"
            culture="neutral" />
          <bindingredirect oldVersion="7.0.0.0-7.1.0.0" newVersion="7.0.0.0"></bindingredirect>
          <codeBase version="7.0.0.0" href="dlls/7.0.0.0/Newtonsoft.Json.dll" />
        </dependentAssembly>
      </assemblyBinding>
```

Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Is my href incorrect ?? dlls folder is in the same level as Content folder in MVC project

Thanks,
Gagan

Comment: Was there a breaking change or functionality change that would not allow you to use 7.0 for all your needs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had also hit the same issue. I solved using codebase methods mentioned in this link.  https://devnet.kentico.com/articles/referencing-multiple-versions-of-the-same-assembly-in-a-single-application

Comment: archive link https://web.archive.org/web/20230701060626/https://devnet.kentico.com/articles/referencing-multiple-versions-of-the-same-assembly-in-a-single-application

Answer (score 10):

Try this assemblyBinding block instead, note the subtle differences...

I've removed the bindingredirect node because you don't need it!

I've changed the slash to backslash in your href attrib

And of course you're going to need 2 codeBase nodes

```
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
   <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed"
        culture="neutral" />
      <!-- You don't need binding redirect, because you're not targeting old version to new,
      ---- instead you're catering to 2 different versions.
        <bindingredirect oldVersion="7.0.0.0-7.1.0.0" newVersion="7.0.0.0"></bindingredirect>
      -->
      <codeBase version="6.0.0.0" href="bin\json6\Newtonsoft.Json.dll" />
      <codeBase version="7.0.0.0" href="dlls\7.0.0.0\Newtonsoft.Json.dll" />
    </dependentAssembly>
  </assemblyBinding>
```

Comment: I made that but still has error 
Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Answer (score 0):

Here's my two cents.
This is what I used for a version upgrade plus a redirection to an old version:

```
<runtime>
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
<bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.0.0.0" newVersion="4.5.0.0" />   
    <codeBase version="4.5.0.0" href="bin/OldJson/Newtonsoft.Json.dll" />
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="5.0.0.0-12.0.0.0" newVersion="12.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
```